# Regular holonomic $\mathcal{D}$-modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, d-modules

An holonomic $\mathcal{D}_X$-module on a smooth algebraic variety over $\mathbb{C}$ is called regular if all its composition factors are minimal extensions of the form $L(Y,N)$, where $N$ is a regular integrable connection and the inclusion $i : Y \rightarrow X$ is affine. Probably is stupid, but I don't understand why $L(Y,M)$ for $M$ an integrable connection on $Y$ is a regular holonomic $\mathcal{D}_X$-module. Here's what I thought (please correct me if anything is wrong):

1. Being $M$ an integrable connection and being integrable connections characterized by $Ch(M) = T^{*}_XX = X \times \{ 0\} \subset T^{*}X$ we have that all its composition factors are integrable connections (from $Ch(M) = Ch(N) \cup Ch(L)$ for an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow N \rightarrow M \rightarrow L \rightarrow 0$)
2. All the composition factor of $M$ are regular integrable connections

How can I conclude from this that $L(Y,M)$ is a regular holonomic $\mathcal{D}_X$-module?

Comment: One way to see this is: regular holonomicity is preserved under direct and exceptional direct image and under taking images of morphisms. Hence, if $M$ is regular holonomic, so is $L(Y,M)$. However, there might be a more direct way to show this when $M$ is a regular integrable connection.